# Cannot connect to password protected wireless networks on a Samsung NC20

Tags: 12.04, wireless, samsung, atheros

My problem is pretty much a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/112411/wireless-security-wpa-wpa2-passwords-not-accepted-wireless-security-none but there was no proper answer there and I couldn't find a way to comment on it, so here it goes again.

I have a Samsung NC20. I was using Natty for a while and all was working fine with the wireless. After upgrading to Oneiric I couldn't connect to protected networks anymore. The networks are detected but when I try to connect, Network Manager just keeps trying until it times out, I guess. Unsecured networks work fine. I upgraded to Precise using an unsecured network but the problem remains.

I tried looking up a solution to this problem on this website and other places but couldn't find anything that worked. I tried WICD instead of Network Manager as some people suggested: same problem. I installed the compat wireless stuff `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.3-precise-generic` but that also didn't help.

As you can imagine this is really annoying and I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. - Here's the output of some possibly relevant commands:

```
$ lspci -v
    00:00.0 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800 Host Bridge (rev 12)
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32

    00:00.1 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 Error Reporting
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

    00:00.2 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 Host Bus Control
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

    00:00.3 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800 PCI to PCI Bridge
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

    00:00.4 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 Power Management Control
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

    00:00.5 PIC: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 APIC and Central Traffic Control (prog-if 20 [IO(X)-APIC])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

    00:00.6 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 Scratch Registers
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

    00:00.7 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 North-South Module Interface Control
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

    00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 Chrome 9 HC3 Integrated Graphics (rev 11) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 10
        Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64M]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 80000000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel modules: viafb

    00:03.0 PCI bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 PCI Express Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
        Memory behind bridge: f5000000-f50fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080300000-00000000804fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

    00:03.1 PCI bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 PCI Express Root Port (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
        Memory behind bridge: f5100000-f51fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080100000-00000000802fffff
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

    00:0d.0 FLASH memory: VIA Technologies, Inc. Secure Digital Memory Card Controller
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 23
        Memory at f5404000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        I/O ports at 4470 [size=8]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: via_sdmmc
        Kernel modules: via-sdmmc

    00:0f.0 IDE interface: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800 Serial ATA and EIDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32
        [virtual] Memory at 000001f0 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
        [virtual] Memory at 000003f0 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [size=1]
        [virtual] Memory at 00000170 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8]
        [virtual] Memory at 00000370 (type 3, non-prefetchable) [size=1]
        I/O ports at 4460 [size=16]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: pata_via
        Kernel modules: pata_via

    00:10.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev a0) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 20
        I/O ports at 4400 [size=32]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

    00:10.1 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev a0) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 22
        I/O ports at 4420 [size=32]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

    00:10.2 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT82xxxxx UHCI USB 1.1 Controller (rev a0) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 21
        I/O ports at 4440 [size=32]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

    00:10.4 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. USB 2.0 (rev 90) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 23
        Memory at f5404800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

    00:11.0 ISA bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX800/VX820 Bus Control and Power Management
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: medium devsel
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel modules: i2c-viapro

    00:11.7 Host bridge: VIA Technologies, Inc. VX8xx South-North Module Interface Control
        Subsystem: VIA Technologies, Inc. Device 7323
        Flags: medium devsel

    00:14.0 Audio device: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8237A/VT8251 HDA Controller (rev 20)
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 67
        Memory at f5400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

    01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device 7131
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
        Memory at f5000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: ath5k
        Kernel modules: ath5k

    02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
        Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device c04e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 66
        Memory at f5100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: sky2
        Kernel modules: sky2
```

and

```
$ ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:77:e6:c7:a3  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
              Interrupt:36 

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
              RX packets:9590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:9590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:736608 (736.6 KB)  TX bytes:736608 (736.6 KB)

    wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d2:e7:63:f7  
              inet addr:10.0.1.74  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::224:d2ff:fee7:63f7/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:23385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:23334 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:20059347 (20.0 MB)  TX bytes:5466444 (5.4 MB)
```

and

```
$ iwconfig
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"ridderzaal"  
              Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 90:84:0D:F0:14:3F   
              Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off
              Link Quality=14/70  Signal level=-96 dBm  
              Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
              Tx excessive retries:53  Invalid misc:7   Missed beacon:0

    eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: The reason you could not comment on that question is that you must have at least 50 reputation before you are allowed to comment everywhere.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have any sugestions regarding my problem by the way?

Comment: Sorry, I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you with the same problem, what worked for me was to compile and install the madwifi drivers. I followed these instructions: http://ubuntucrack.blogspot.nl/2010/07/howto-install-madwifi-drivers-for.html with the difference that instead of `ath_pci` I had to activate the `wlan` module (step 14).

Afterwards the wifi would not come up after putting the computer to sleep. Again, what worked for me was to go to the file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/55NetworkManager` and add a line with `ifconfig wifi0 up` right before the line with `resume_nm`.

Best of luck!